# Diagonal matrix with all zero entries

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Is it possible for a diagonalisable and non-zero n x n matrix A to have a diagonal matrix D with all zero diagonal entries?

Comment: No: when you conjugate the 0 matrix back you can only get the 0 matrix. In symbols, if $0_n=SAS^{-1}$ then $A=S^{-1}0_nS=0_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is diagonalizable and all its eigenvalues are zero, then $A=0$. Because there is a basis of eigenvectors $f_1,\ldots,f_n$, and all satisfy $Af_j=0$; so $A=0$.

Comment: So if matrix A is non-zero and diagonalisable then the Trace of the diagonal Matrix D must be non-zero?

Comment: No. The eigenvalues can add to zero without being zero themselves.

Comment: You're right... Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. I don't mind if you do it or not for my answer, but usually in this site if you find something useful/interesting the suggestion is that you upvote it using the up arrow. The voting system is an essential part of the SE network.